# how to solve Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier while passing a string to javascript function using onclick inside PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I am getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

and when I change `onclick='EditClient(\"$edit_query\");` to single quotes I get

> Unexpected End of input error.

The table is getting displayed with data from mysql database but I am trying to use the content of the php $edit_query string and send it to the javascript EditClient Function to set textboxes on the same page with update button.

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Clients.css">
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    DisplayClients();
});

function EditClient(x){

    alert(x);
}

function DisplayClients(){

    <?php 

        $query = "SELECT * from clients";
        $res_string = "<table border='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>GST No</th><th>Telephone</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);

        $edit_query = "";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $edit_query = $edit_query.$row["cid"]."#".$row["cname"]."#".$row["caddress"]."#".$row["cgstno"]."#".$row["ctel"];
        $res_string = $res_string."<tr><td>".$row["cid"]."</td><td>".$row["cname"]."</td><td>".$row["caddress"]."</td><td>".$row["cgstno"]."</td><td>".$row["ctel"]."</td><td class='edit' onclick='EditClient(\"$edit_query\");'>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";

        }       

        $res_string = $res_string."</table>";
    ?>

    var displaytable = "<?php echo $res_string;?>";

    $("#clienttable").html(displaytable);

}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$res_string = $res_string."<tr><td>".$row["cid"]."</td><td>".$row["cname"]."</td><td>".$row["caddress"]."</td><td>".$row["cgstno"]."</td><td>".$row["ctel"]."</td><td class='edit' onclick=\"EditClient(\"$edit_query\");\">Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";
```

I think you should have double quotes on click: 
`<td class='edit' onclick=\"EditClient(\"$edit_query\");\"`

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" Thats all it says in the chrome console

Comment: Your suggestion was right. I just had to put the parameter using this \' and not \''. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

*Unexpected* generally means it should not be there.

Which leads me to conclude echo should be used as a function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $res_string = $res_string."<tr><td>".$row["cid"]."</td><td>".$row["cname"]."</td><td>".$row["caddress"]."</td><td>".$row["cgstno"]."</td><td>".$row["ctel"]."</td><td class='edit' onclick=\"EditClient('$edit_query');\">Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";
```

This worked